Get Deployment status for Individual managed weblogic servers in WLST script
We deployed application and target into Cluster, we need to get deployment status for individual managed server using WLST script.
I'm expecting WLST command to get as like as below for admin console.
Server- -> deployment -> status
Note: Some time application goes failed status in one managed server, other targeted servers are ACTIVE status, have to monitor individual server deployment status.
I'm not able to get Individual managed server deployment status .
It's shows only overall deployment status.
